# How to disable X support for emacs

Tags: debian, emacs

After I install `emacs` package on Debian 7 (Wheezy), when I start it up on a GUI terminal, it opens a GUI (GTK-based). I would rather it just run from the terminal.

Comment: Maybe it's aliased - see `alias emacs`, or maybe you should check for another command name: `apropos emacs` will give you a pointer. Also, see `type emacs`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can start emacs with the `--no-window-system` command line option (`-nw` for short).

```
$ emacs --no-window-system
```

Debian also offers a package that has X disabled, `emacs-nox`. It Conflicts with the normal `emacs23` package (the main one, which runs X when available). It removes the need to specify the `--no-window-system` option.

Comment: You can also do `DISPLAY= emacs`. With `$DISPLAY` unset, `emacs` just uses the terminal.

Comment: @Alexios good point .. that's one of the strengths of Linux/Unix, so many ways to accomplish tasks.